# Symmetries of separable potential

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, symmetry, potential, lie-algebra

For separable potential, say $x^4+y^4$, its symmetry are degenerate.
Is that a generic case to every separable potential?  I will explain my question:

The potential $x^4+y^4$ has $A_1, B_1, A_2, B_2, E$  symmetries. However, all of them are degenerate. Quantum mechanically, the energy level are all degenerate and one can consider, for example, only the $A_1$ symmetry, why?

Comment: I don't think the notation you use is standard. What are these symmetries? What does "separable" mean?

Comment: I think by separable he mean the potential will lead to a solution of the form $\psi(x,y) = f(x)g(y)$.